# XML advanced search

Tags: notepad++, search, xml

I got XML file which contains 130k lines. Let's say it has a lof of tags which has repeating sub tags.

```
<tag1>
<subtag1></subtag1>
<subtag2>something</subtag2>
</tag1>
...
...
<tag1>
<subtag1>something</subtag1>
<subtag2>something</subtag2>
</tag1>
```

and all  should be same amount of lines. I would like to search through the whole file (130k lines) to find tags who contain more or less lines than it should. What appropriate method for that would be? Using Notepad++ right now.

Comment: Sounds like you want to validate the XML schema. So write a schema and use a schema validator. Notepad++ is not a suitable tool.

Answer (score 1):

This XML

```
$ cat Petras.xml
<doc>
<tag1>
<subtag1></subtag1>
<subtag2>something</subtag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
<subtag1>something</subtag1>
<subtag2>something</subtag2>
</tag1>
</doc>
```

Can be validated against this XSD

```
$ cat Petras.xsd
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="doc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="tag1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="subtag1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element name="subtag2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Using, for example, xmllint

```
$ xmllint --schema Petras.xsd Petras.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<tag1>
<subtag1/>
<subtag2>something</subtag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
<subtag1>something</subtag1>
<subtag2>something</subtag2>
</tag1>
</doc>
Petras.xml validates
```

Comment: I believe `maxOccurs="unbounded"` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Daniel: good point, thanks, answer updated accordingly.